# Angularjs material modal window is not centered to screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am using angular material modal to create a pop up window.
The problem is the window is not centered to the screen.

[image]

this is the controller side:

```
$scope.showTabwtr = function(ev) {
$mdDialog.show({
  controller: DialogController,
  templateUrl: 'templates/jargon/wtr.tmpl.html',
  parent: angular.element(document.body),
  windowClass: 'center-modal',
  targetEvent: ev,
  clickOutsideToClose:true
})
    .then(function(answer) {
      $scope.status = 'You said the information was "' + answer + '".';
    }, function() {
      $scope.status = 'You cancelled the dialog.';
    });
  }
```

How do i make reference to the css file in this code? thank you for your help

Comment: Why don't you just include your css-file in your index.html or wtr.tmpl.html?

Comment: I did. It is not applied and i don't know why